# Giving an array the same ordering as another array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two vectors, `a` and `b`, of the same length, each having some random order. I want `a` to have its same order, and for `b` to be sorted according to `a`.

So for example:

```
a = [5 4 1 2]
b = [7 8 9 6]
```

now I want the highest value of `b` to be in the position of the highest value of `a`, and the second highest value of `b` to be in the position of the second highest value of `a`, etc; that is:

```
b = [9 8 6 7]
```

I have tried

```
[~, indices] = sort(a)
b(indices)
```

but this yields

```
ans = [9 6 8 7]
```

which is clearly not right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to maintain `a`'s original order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable 'indices' doesn't store exactly what you expected. Revise the help of the find function. This sligtly different code may be your answer:

```
a = [5 4 1 2];
b = [7 8 9 6];

[~, idx] = sort(a);
b(idx) = sort(b)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're almost right.  You need to sort both of the results and use `indices` to index into the **sorted** vector `b`.  You also want to use the `'descend'` flag to sort the values from highest to lowest first.

So do this:

```
a = [5 4 1 2];
b = [7 8 9 6];

[~,indices] = sort(a,'descend');
bsort = sort(b,'descend');
bsort(indices)
```

`indices` in this case will give you the positions of where each value in `a` appears in sorted form in descending order.  If you want to align up the values of `b` so that they conform to the same order as `a`, you would need to sort `b` in descending order as well so that the values line up, then use `indices` to index into the sorted version of `b` to complete the task.

We get:

```
ans =

 9     8     6     7
```

Comment: I was trying out something similar. Strangely enough, this only works with the `descend` option, not if you sort the vector in ascending order. Although you could of course obtain this behaviour using `indices(end:1)`

Comment: @WouterKuijsters - Yes that's what I did.  You probably left that comment as I was putting in a blurb about why `descend` was needed.

Comment: my confusion lay mainly with the fact that `sort(a,'ascend')` and `sort(b,'ascend')` do not work - your output would become `8 9 6 7`. I find it kind of strange this only works in descending order, and can't really find out why ascending doesn't work. I'm probably too tired...

Comment: @WouterKuijsters - Because the OP wants the **highest** values to appear first, followed by the lowest values in the end.  Note that the first element of the output needs to be positioned where `a` has its **highest** value, which is why `descend` is needed.  If the opposite problem was required, where the **lowest** values need to appear first, then `ascend` can be used.

Comment: @WouterKuijsters The `8 9 6 7` makes sense if ascending order is respected.  As such, the `6` appears where the position of `1` appears in `a`.  Similarly, the `7` appears where the position of `2` appears in `a` and so on.  We are positioning `b` so the values are increasing in ascending order with respect to `a`.  Since we want the **opposite** problem, we must reverse it.  FWIW, I was quite confused as you were on why `ascend` didn't work until I worked it out on paper.

Comment: I have to say I was utterly confused for a while, but you're right. Good old pen and paper to the rescue!

Comment: @WouterKuijsters - Yes that is certainly correct.  With that logic, you should get the same result.  Look at the first position where `a` is 5.  This is the highest value that appears in `a`.  The corresponding highest value of `b` is 9, and so the first position is `9` for the output.  Next, take a look at the second position of `a` which is 4. This is the second highest value of `a`, and the second highest value of `b` is `8` and so the output here will be 8.  Look at the third position of `a`, which is `1`. This is the **lowest** value of `a` and the corresponding lowest value of `b` is 6.

Comment: @WouterKuijsters - Finally, the last position of `a` is 2.  This corresponds to the second lowest value in `a`, and the corresponding second lowest value in `b` is 7, and thus we get 7.  Yeah, it was certainly confusing... nothing beats pen and paper!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there are duplicate values in `a` or `b`. For example, if `a=[1 1 2 0]` (with the maximum value in the third position) and `b=[3 4 5 6]` this yields `bsort=[4 6 5 3]` (with the maximum value in the second position) and not either of the correct solutions `[4 5 6 3]` or `[5 4 6 3]`.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron - Looks like it doesn't work with duplicate entries.  Glad you found your answer though!

Answer (score 2):

After all, it turns out you can use the `ascend` option, although in a bit different way:

```
a=[5 5 6 3];
b=[1 2 3 4];
[asorted,indices] = sort(a,'ascend');
bsorted = sort(b,'ascend');
output(indices) = bsorted
```

which yields:

```
output =

     2     3     4     1
```

Comment: I see Jordi actually beat me to it, and his code is more efficient. Oh well, learned something anyway!

Comment: I like your answer because it's more verbose.  I'm working out why mine doesn't work with duplicates.

Comment: Jordi's works with duplicates, so I have accepted it. Thanks for your help anyway though, you two.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron - No worries.  Thanks for posing an interesting problem!